# Bash terminals launched from windows UI have an invalid `!::=::\` variable set

Tags: bash, terminal, environment-variables, msys2

When I run `printenv` one of the returned variables is `!::=::\`. I noticed that the variable exists because docker does not work correctly with it set.

```
$ printenv | grep ::
!::=::\

$ docker stack deploy keycloak -c keycloak.yml
unexpected environment "=::=::\\"
```

**This variable only exists if my terminal is launched from the graphical interface. If I launch the same process manually from another terminal, the variable does not exist.**

It is not possible to unset the variable in bash.

```
$ unset !::
bash: :: unrecognized history modifier

$ unset \!::

$ env | grep ::
!::=::\

$ printenv | grep :: | cat -A
!::=::\$

$ set +H

$ unset !::

$ unset \!::

$ env | grep ::
!::=::\
```

How can I prevent the `!::=::\` environment variable from being created when the terminal is launched using the start menu?

The variable exists in both Git-bash (Msys) and MSys2.

Comment: Related: [How to unset bash variable `!::=::\`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/746624/108618). Not a repost though (good). This link is for users with the same or a similar problem. They may find the other question useful as well.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/251174/5132 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reported in the Docker post
[docker stack deploy Fails When Run From cmd.exe on Windows with CLI v23+ #4078](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/4078).

The explanation is that when you run a command from the
graphical interface, it is implicitly invokes `cmd.exe`, which means
that it also inherits the environment of CMD.

A user furnished a link to the article
[What are these strange =C: environment variables?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100506-00/?p=14133)
where is found the explanation:

`cmd.exe` basically keeps special environment variables with blank names
to support old MS-DOS functionality. These are the environment variables
that Docker stumbles over.

In this spirit, another user has recommended changing the error message
from "unexpected environment ..." to "unexpected environment variable ...".

Comment: Wow. That is amazing. I originally asked the question at the Unix stack exchange, where a workaround is created: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/746624/how-to-unset-bash-variable